# How do functions get into different namespaces in the Duct framework?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

When you fire up a new Clojure project based on the Duct web framework, the `main.clj` file contains the following require clause:

```
:require 
... 
    [duct.util.system :refer [load-system]]
...
```

But when I inspect the Duct source, `src/duct/util/system.clj` doesn't define a `load-system` function. In fact, `load-system` appears to be defined in `lein-template/resources/leiningen/new/duct/base/dev.clj`, in the `dev` namespace.

So: how does this function end up in the `duct.util.system` namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is that you looked at the `duct.util.system` source on master branch where it has been changed since the version you are using in your project:

- [master latest version doesn't have `load-system` var](https://github.com/duct-framework/duct/blob/75202011075365363e773eff7f9bd6377afe7239/duct/src/duct/util/system.clj)
- [0.8.2 version do have `load-system` var](https://github.com/duct-framework/duct/blob/0.8.2/duct/src/duct/util/system.clj#L44)

Comment: Ha! What a fool I am. There is so much ambient magic in Clojure/Leiningen that I just assumed there would be some kind of exotic meta-programming/code-generation going on.

Comment: Next time I will remember to use the pickaxe! `git log -S"load-system"`